# Sequelizejs getting result from 2 mysql table by 1 query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am developing a project with Nodejs and mysql. I am using Sequelize as a ORM. I have a problem is that I would like to get results from 2 different table by 1 query. Do i need to make a callback structure or Sequelize has its own function for it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be more clear about those 2 tables.
Do they have any [associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html) ?
If yes, then sequelize does provide joins, Just like mysql does join.
Though Sequelize does not support [Unions](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4293) directly,  But you can very well use a [raw query](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html) in such cases.
Or you can use [Promises](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-an-alternative-to-callbacks/), basically `Promise.all`, which would help in making those 2 queries simultaneously.

**Based on the comment**.
You can very well use promises in that case,

So say you have 2 tables A and B.
You can do something like

```
return Promise.all([query for first table, query    for second table])
```

I would suggest reading more about promises in JS.

Comment: These are totally different 2 tables. They have a relationship but in this case,  I don't use the relationship. I would like to serve data from these tables via Express. I would like to serve these data in same GET callback scope.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you to retrieve all data by one query:

```
sequelize.query("select * from tbl_1 union all select * from tbl_2").then(function(rows){
    console.log("data",rows)
})
```